# mvc3 .net - Is there a way to completely hide a hidden field in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I can use:  @Html.HiddenFor to hide a field on a form, however, you can still see the value of the hidden field using "view source".

Is there a way in MVC3 to hide the hidden field in view source as well - I want to completely hide the primary key from the user, but still pass it from the view to the controller via the model, when posting the form.

Any code snippet or link to an example is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, put simple no. If you intend to send the key through the form, there is no way to hide the data from the source.

As you don't mention what primary key or what kind of form data you are posting, it's hard to give any other suggestions. If it is the primary key of the user, you can of course use the login session, instead of sending the key through the form, but in any other case, I'm afraid you have to reveal the primary key through the source.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide a field from a source.

But in certain situations you can try to do something else like not passing the ID to the view. Keep it on controller side, and use it on the form submit. Of course you need to be carefull with that but it's doable with  TempData or ViewData . Here's a hint http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/21/asp.net-mvc-helpers-for-repopulating-a-form.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback chaps.
I thought you might not be able to do this. Is this not a security issue, if the user of the form can see the primary key userId in the source?

Comment: I would say that it is normal to reveal some kind of an identifier for a particular record, but that also depends on what's type of data you're working with. If that's let say, a BookId for a book that user wants to buy - no reason to hide that id from him. If that's something more sensitive you may want to mask your ID with  SHA1 hash plus add record ownership / permission control

Comment: thanks @torm,  I think I might look into sessions to see if I can hold the userId there and then get the controller to use the session for the id.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep  information across multiple requests, then utilize the TempData collection on the server side as it's backed by session but designed precisely to keep information for short durations.  Alternatively, if you must push the data to the client via hidden or other html with zero height, then encrypt it using symmetric encryption or at least base64 encoding ( very poor man approach to keep it away from curious eyes).